# Python Pandas to_datetime returns to NaT

Tags: python, pandas

First thanx for reading.

I have a database that comes from sql to excel and like this.
[image]

and the dtypes;
[image]

before turning date columns to time, i m trying to get rid of None(s) by;

```
df.fillna("",inplace=True)
```

then

```
df1[["ACT_START_DATE","ACT_END_DATE"]]=df1[["ACT_START_DATE","ACT_END_DATE"]].apply(pd.to_datetime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

but empty values turn to NaT

[image]

How can i get rid of those NaT(s)? Aim is empty cell

Comment: NaT is expected in this case. NaT is similar to NaN for floats. What's your desired output?

Comment: How do you Want to fill the cells with None date ? If you Want to keep the cell empty you can pass the argument errors='ignore' in your call of pd.to_datetime...

Comment: @AlexanderVolkovsky aim is "Empty Cell" or blank.

Comment: @Renaud errors="ignore" doesnt work... Still gives NaT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to have a `datetime64` column with the string placeholders. It must be an `object` column. In turn, this will not allow you to use time series/datetime features of pandas. I recommend ignoring `NaT` during the processing stage and using the [`fillna({<date_column_name>: ""})`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) method just before exporting the dataframe.